# How to exclude ISNULL from WHERE condition with multiple conditions?

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2008

I have the following data:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
    Id INT,
    [Date_1] DATETIME2,
    [Date_2] DATETIME2
)

INSERT INTO @tbl ([Id], [Date_1], [Date_2]) VALUES
(1, '2018-08-15 16:05:20.000', NULL),
(2, '2018-08-15 16:05:20.000', NULL),
(3, '2018-08-15 16:05:20.000', NULL),
(4, '2018-08-20 00:00:00.000', NULL),
(5, NULL, NULL),
(6, '2018-08-30 14:02:08.000', '2018-09-05 12:31:30.530')
```

And I have a query which perfectly works with various conditions:

```
SELECT *
FROM @tbl AS t
WHERE
    (ISNULL(t.[Date_1], '1900-1-1') BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo) OR
    (ISNULL(t.[Date_2], '1900-1-1') BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo)
```

**The first case**.

```
DECLARE @DateFrom DATE = '1900-01-01', @DateTo DATE = '9999-12-30' -- result one. The overall count is 6 rows
```

Result would be:

[image]

**The second case**. If I change `@DateFrom` and `@DateTo`:

```
DECLARE @DateFrom DATE = '2018-08-15', @DateTo DATE = '2018-08-16' -- result two. The overall count is 3 rows
```

Then result would be:

[image]

**The third case**. If I change `@DateFrom` and `@DateTo`:

```
DECLARE @DateFrom DATE = '2018-09-05', @DateTo DATE = '2018-09-06' -- result three. The overall count is 1 row
```

Then result would be:

[image]

My question is how can it possible to exclude `ISNULL` from `WHERE`    statement?
I've tried different approaches, but they give me incorrect results:

```
SELECT *
FROM @tbl AS t
WHERE
((t.[Date_1] IS NOT NULL AND t.[Date_1]  BETWEEN @DateFrom
    AND @DateTo) OR t.[Date_1] IS NULL) OR
((t.[Date_2] IS NOT NULL AND t.[Date_2] BETWEEN @DateFrom
    AND @DateTo) OR t.[Date_2] IS NULL)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I cannot set `@DateFrom` and `@DateTo` to `NULL`.

Comment: NULL is unknown and it is up to the programmer to tell SQL how to handle nulls. So, what happens when the dates are null? should they match or not?

Comment: [BETWEEN is evil](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: @SalmanA NULL should not be matched. I mean is it possible to eliminate ISNULL, but the result should be the same like in my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, using `BETWEEN` to compare datetime datatype is incorrect. For example your original query does not allow you to select all `2018-08-15` dates but exclude the exact value of `2018-08-16 00:00:00`.

Secondly it looks like you want a "catch all" query.

I would use the following WHERE clause:

```
WHERE Date_1 >= @DateFrom AND Date_1 < @DateTo
OR    Date_2 >= @DateFrom AND Date_2 < @DateTo
OR    @DateFrom IS NULL AND @DateTo IS NULL
```

Then set the values as follows:

```
-- catch all
SET @DateFrom = NULL
SET @DateTo   = NULL

-- all dates between 2018-08-15 00:00 and 2018-08-15 23:59:59.9999999
SET @DateFrom = '2018-08-15'
SET @DateTo   = '2018-08-16'

-- all dates between 2018-09-05 00:00 and 2018-09-05 23:59:59.9999999
SET @DateFrom = '2018-09-05'
SET @DateTo   = '2018-09-06'
```

Comment: I really appreciate your reply, however I cannot edit parameters `@DateFrom` and `@DateTo`. Maybe you have another suggestion?

Comment: Okay, does the input `(1900-01-01, 9999-12-30)` mean include all rows including nulls? BTW, date has a range of 0001-01-01 through 9999-12-31.

Comment: yeah, you are right!  It means to inlcude all rows

Comment: Hard code this special case in the where clause as the third condition `OR @DateFrom = '1900-01-01' AND @DateTo = '9999-12-30'`

Comment: yeah, it works! Thank you. Just one question, please. Is it possible to get results without hard coding `OR @DateFrom = '1900-01-01' AND @DateTo = '9999-12-30'`?

Comment: You either hard code the date in ISNULL like you were doing earlier or here. Your choice.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just want all records when (@DateFrom, @DateTo) are the minimum & maximum date literals.

Then this query returns that.

```
SELECT  * 
FROM @tbl AS t     
WHERE ( (t.[Date_1] >= @DateFrom AND t.[Date_1] < DATEADD(day,1,@DateTo)) 
     OR (t.[Date_2] >= @DateFrom AND t.[Date_2] < DATEADD(day,1,@DateTo))
     OR (@DateFrom <= '1900-01-01' AND @DateTo >= '9999-01-01')
);
```

The `BETWEEN` were replaced since Date_1 and Date_2 aren't `DATE` types.

**Demo**

> ```
> DECLARE @tbl TABLE 
> (
>     Id int,
>     [Date_1] DateTime2,
>     [Date_2] DateTime2
> )
> Insert Into @tbl ([Id],[Date_1],[Date_2])
> Values 
>   (1, '2018-08-15 16:05:20.000', NULL)
> , (2, '2018-08-15 16:05:20.000', NULL)
> , (3, '2018-08-15 16:05:20.000', NULL)
> , (4, '2018-08-20 00:00:00.000', NULL)
> , (5, NULL,NULL)
> , (6, '2018-08-30 14:02:08.000', '2018-09-05 12:31:30.530');
>
> DECLARE @DateFrom DATE, @DateTo DATE;
>
> SELECT @DateFrom = '1900-01-01', @DateTo = '9999-12-30'; 
> -- result 1.  The overall count is 6 rows
>     
> SELECT  * 
> FROM @tbl AS t     
> WHERE ( (t.[Date_1] >= @DateFrom AND t.[Date_1] < DATEADD(day,1,@DateTo)) 
>      OR (t.[Date_2] >= @DateFrom AND t.[Date_2] < DATEADD(day,1,@DateTo))
>      OR (@DateFrom <= '1900-01-01' AND @DateTo >= '9999-01-01')
> );
>        
> SELECT @DateFrom = '2018-08-15', @DateTo = '2018-08-16';
> -- result two. The overall count is 3 rows   
>
> SELECT  * 
> FROM @tbl AS t     
> WHERE ( (t.[Date_1] >= @DateFrom AND t.[Date_1] < DATEADD(day,1,@DateTo)) 
>      OR (t.[Date_2] >= @DateFrom AND t.[Date_2] < DATEADD(day,1,@DateTo))
>      OR (@DateFrom <= '1900-01-01' AND @DateTo >= '9999-01-01')
> );
>
> SET @DateFrom = '2018-09-05'; SET @DateTo = '2018-09-06';
> -- result three. The overall count is 1 row
>
> SELECT  * 
> FROM @tbl AS t     
> WHERE ( (t.[Date_1] >= @DateFrom AND t.[Date_1] < DATEADD(day,1,@DateTo)) 
>      OR (t.[Date_2] >= @DateFrom AND t.[Date_2] < DATEADD(day,1,@DateTo))
>      OR (@DateFrom <= '1900-01-01' AND @DateTo >= '9999-01-01')
> );
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Id | Date_1                      | Date_2                     
> -: | :-------------------------- | :--------------------------
>  1 | 2018-08-15 16:05:20.0000000 | null                       
>  2 | 2018-08-15 16:05:20.0000000 | null                       
>  3 | 2018-08-15 16:05:20.0000000 | null                       
>  4 | 2018-08-20 00:00:00.0000000 | null                       
>  5 | null                        | null                       
>  6 | 2018-08-30 14:02:08.0000000 | 2018-09-05 12:31:30.5300000
>
> Id | Date_1                      | Date_2
> -: | :-------------------------- | :-----
>  1 | 2018-08-15 16:05:20.0000000 | null  
>  2 | 2018-08-15 16:05:20.0000000 | null  
>  3 | 2018-08-15 16:05:20.0000000 | null  
>
> Id | Date_1                      | Date_2                     
> -: | :-------------------------- | :--------------------------
>  6 | 2018-08-30 14:02:08.0000000 | 2018-09-05 12:31:30.5300000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bfa01109affd3a3138a720843cc7f0aa)*

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, it gives incorrect results for all three cases shown in images.

Comment: right, there's that other. checking.

Comment: @Learner Fixed. See update.

Comment: I just noticed that Date_1 & Date_2 are DATETIME2. Then you don't want to use a `BETWEEN`.  Because `myDateTime BETWEEN '2022-01-20' AND '2022-01-22'`  translates to `myDateTime BETWEEN '2022-01-20 00:00:00' AND '2022-01-22 00:00:00'`